# Android compare datetime

Tags: android, datetime

I'm trying to compare two datetimes but I can't get it to work.

```
    public void time () {
        Calendar c11 = Calendar.getInstance ();
        c11.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
        c11.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        c11.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
        c11.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Calendar c12 = Calendar.getInstance ();
        c12.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 0);
        c12.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
        c12.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0 );
        c12.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        c11.getTime();
        c12.getTime();
        boolean k = c11.equals(c12);
        if (k==true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(
              getContext(),
              "Wow these two times are the same!",
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The milliseconds of the 2 time values are different so the equality comparison is going to return false.
2. Why are you adding 0 days to both calendar instances?  That doesn't do anything.

Comment: Why are the values different c11 and c12 are both set to be the same?

Comment: No they are not the same.  Like I just said, the milliseconds are different.  You need to set the milliseconds to 0 on both of them.  Right now the milliseconds are set to whatever the current time was when you called Calendar.getInstance()

Comment: Right so is there anyother way i can compare these two ?

Comment: Java Date and Calendar objects are always going to include milliseconds.  You need to do the following: c11.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0); c12.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);  Then the equality comparison will return true.

Answer (score 1):

```
 public void onDateSelected(DateTime dateSelected) {
    DateTime currentDateTime = new DateTime(); 

    try{
        /* If you want to compare only date from DateTime object then,
           you can use "yyyy-MM-dd" format and split the string from T like: 
           dateSelected.toString().split("T") and use str1[0] to parse */  

        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ");

        String str1 = dateSelected.toString();
        Date selectedDate = formatter.parse(str1);

        String str2 = currentDateTime.toString();
        Date currentDate = formatter.parse(str2);

        if (selectedDate.compareTo(currentDate)<0)
        {
            System.out.println("current date is Greater than my selected date");
        }

    }catch (ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Can we send the format as parameter for this function to make it more generic?
public void onDateSelected(DateTime dateSelected, String format){
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
...
}

Comment: Yes, you can do it like this :)

Comment: Thanks Shujat it will help